# Could not commit JPA transaction: Transaction marked as rollbackOnly

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm using Spring and Hibernate in one of the applications that I'm working on and I've got a problem with handling of transactions.

I've got a service class that loads some entities from the database, modifies some of their values and then (when everything is valid) commits these changes to the database. If the new values are invalid (which I can only check after setting them) I do not want to persist the changes. To prevent Spring/Hibernate from saving the changes I throw an exception in the method. This however results in the following error:

```
Could not commit JPA transaction: Transaction marked as rollbackOnly
```

And this is the service:

```
@Service
class MyService {

  @Transactional(rollbackFor = MyCustomException.class)
  public void doSth() throws MyCustomException {
    //load entities from database
    //modify some of their values
    //check if they are valid
    if(invalid) { //if they arent valid, throw an exception
      throw new MyCustomException();
    }

  }
}
```

And this is how I invoke it:

```
class ServiceUser {
  @Autowired
  private MyService myService;

  public void method() {
    try {
      myService.doSth();
    } catch (MyCustomException e) {
      // ...
    }        
  }
}
```

What I'd expect to happen: No changes to the database and no exception visible to the user.

What happens: No changes to the database but the app crashes with:

```
org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction;
nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction marked as rollbackOnly
```

It's correctly setting the transaction to rollbackOnly but why is the rollback crashing with an exception?

Comment: My guess is that ServiceUser.method() is itself transactional. It shouldn't be. Post the full stack trace.

Comment: try using `noRollbackFor` instead of `rollbackFor` in the `@Transactional` annotation

Comment: @JBNizet Wow good guess, there was actually an `@Transactional` annotation at ServiceUser's class declaration. After removing that it works perfectly. Could you please post your comment as an answer (and maybe give a short explanation of the reason why it shouldnt be transactional)?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

My guess is that `ServiceUser.method()` is itself transactional. It shouldn't be. Here's the reason why.

Here's what happens when a call is made to your `ServiceUser.method()` method:

1. the transactional interceptor intercepts the method call, and starts a transaction, because no transaction is already active
2. the method is called
3. the method calls MyService.doSth()
4. the transactional interceptor intercepts the method call, sees that a transaction is already active, and doesn't do anything
5. doSth() is executed and throws an exception
6. the transactional interceptor intercepts the exception, marks the transaction as rollbackOnly, and propagates the exception
7. ServiceUser.method() catches the exception and returns
8. the transactional interceptor, since it has started the transaction, tries to commit it. But Hibernate refuses to do it because the transaction is marked as rollbackOnly, so Hibernate throws an exception. The transaction interceptor signals it to the caller by throwing an exception wrapping the hibernate exception.

Now if `ServiceUser.method()` is not transactional, here's what happens:

1. the method is called
2. the method calls MyService.doSth()
3. the transactional interceptor intercepts the method call, sees that no transaction is already active, and thus starts a transaction
4. doSth() is executed and throws an exception
5. the transactional interceptor intercepts the exception. Since it has started the transaction, and since an exception has been thrown, it rollbacks the transaction, and propagates the exception
6. ServiceUser.method() catches the exception and returns

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. One question though: What would I do if I needed a transaction inside `ServiceUser.method()`? For example if I wanted to access lazily-loaded associations of entities?

Comment: You could probably use REQUIRES_NEW for the doSth() method. The doSth method would then execute in its own transaction which could be rollbacked without affecting the method() transaction.

Comment: Thanks again! Setting `propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW` on `doSth` works!

Comment: I am not able to get point 6,8. If Transactional Interceptor knows there is rollback why does it tries to commit ?

Comment: @balboa_21 good question. " If Transactional Interceptor knows there is rollback why does it tries to commit ? " point 6.

Answer (score 31):

> Could not commit JPA transaction: Transaction marked as rollbackOnly

**This exception occurs when you invoke nested methods/services also marked as `@Transactional`**. JB Nizet explained the mechanism in detail. I'd like to add some **scenarios** when it happens as well as some **ways to avoid it**.

Suppose we have two Spring services: `Service1` and `Service2`. From our program we call `Service1.method1()` which in turn calls `Service2.method2()`:

```
class Service1 {
    @Transactional
    public void method1() {
        try {
            ...
            service2.method2();
            ...
        } catch (Exception e) {
            ...
        }
    }
}

class Service2 {
    @Transactional
    public void method2() {
        ...
        throw new SomeException();
        ...
    }
}
```

`SomeException` is unchecked (extends RuntimeException) unless stated otherwise.

Scenarios:

1. Transaction marked for rollback by exception thrown out of `method2`. This is our default case explained by JB Nizet.
2. Annotating `method2` as `@Transactional(readOnly = true)` still marks transaction for rollback (exception thrown when exiting from `method1`).
3. Annotating both `method1` and `method2` as `@Transactional(readOnly = true)` still marks transaction for rollback (exception thrown when exiting from `method1`).
4. Annotating `method2` with `@Transactional(noRollbackFor = SomeException)` prevents marking transaction for rollback (**no exception** thrown when exiting from `method1`).
5. Suppose `method2` belongs to `Service1`. Invoking it from `method1` does not go through Spring's proxy, i.e. Spring is unaware of `SomeException` thrown out of `method2`. Transaction is **not marked for rollback** in this case.
6. Suppose `method2` is not annotated with `@Transactional`. Invoking it from `method1` does go through Spring's proxy, but Spring pays no attention to exceptions thrown. Transaction is **not marked for rollback** in this case.
7. Annotating `method2` with `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)` makes `method2` start new transaction. That second transaction is marked for rollback upon exit from `method2` but original transaction is unaffected in this case (**no exception** thrown when exiting from `method1`).
8. In case `SomeException` is *checked* (does not extend RuntimeException), Spring by default does not mark transaction for rollback when intercepting checked exceptions (**no exception** thrown when exiting from `method1`).

See all scenarios tested in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/yarosla/794fdff3a7c9448faa18d484066b4fa8).

Comment: Great info. Right now your point 7 came to my help but in my case suppose `Service1.method1().dao1()` is happening and I want **if Service2.method2()  fails(or do a rollback) then`Service1.method1().dao1()` should also do a rollback**?

Comment: @balboa_21In case you do want to roll back, just let exception from inner method fly through outer Transactional method as well (or re-throw).

Comment: but if services are catching exceptions ? . Am I correct here  "if one transaction is active then in case of another service with `@Transaction` will reuse it" ?. So wouldn't there be any way of making transaction failure cascading

Comment: @balboa_21 Transaction reuse depends on `propagation` setting. E.g. `REQUIRES_NEW` does not reuse transaction therefore even when inner  transaction is marked for rollback, outer transaction is not affected. Throwing exception is the preferred way of marking transaction for rollback, although you can use transaction manager API directly, eg. see http://stackoverflow.com/a/34933457/697313

Comment: Thanks I was able to solve my issued after 3 days debugging

Answer (score 2):

For those who can't (or don't want to) setup a debugger to track down the original exception which was causing the rollback-flag to get set, you can just add a bunch of debug statements throughout your code to find the lines of code which trigger the rollback-only flag:

```
logger.debug("Is rollbackOnly: " + TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus().isRollbackOnly());
```

Adding this throughout the code allowed me to narrow down the root cause, by numbering the debug statements and looking to see where the above method goes from returning "false" to "true".

Answer (score 1):

As explained @Yaroslav Stavnichiy if a service is marked as transactional spring tries to handle transaction itself. If any exception occurs then a rollback operation performed. If in your scenario ServiceUser.method() is not performing any transactional operation you can use @Transactional.TxType annotation. 'NEVER' option is used to manage that method outside transactional context.

Transactional.TxType reference doc is [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/transaction/Transactional.TxType.html).

Answer (score 1):

Save sub object first and then call final repository save method.

```
@PostMapping("/save")
    public String save(@ModelAttribute("shortcode") @Valid Shortcode shortcode, BindingResult result) {
        Shortcode existingShortcode = shortcodeService.findByShortcode(shortcode.getShortcode());
        if (existingShortcode != null) {
            result.rejectValue(shortcode.getShortcode(), "This shortode is already created.");
        }
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "redirect:/shortcode/create";
        }
        **shortcode.setUser(userService.findByUsername(shortcode.getUser().getUsername()));**
        shortcodeService.save(shortcode);
        return "redirect:/shortcode/create?success";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For me this happened due to constraint violation , when I was trying to update not null field with null value using save.