# Spring JPA Service - Validation - Runtime Exception

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a API , That looks like below

```
@Transaction
void method (){
try{
  service1.insertOne();
  service2.insertTwo();
}
catch(Exception ex) {
// log exception
}
}
```

In Service classes, I am checking for certain validation and I am throwing an exception which is a subclass of `RuntimeException`. When i throw this exception, `javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction marked as rollbackOnly` . While it is preventing the data in the first service from not being inserted , since the second service validation has failed, I am not quite quite sure if this is the right way to handle this scenario.

In case if the Exception is not a sub-class of `Exception`, even when the validation for service2 fails , data in service1 gets inserted, but i do see the custom exception being thrown. So i am not sure where i am going wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> the Spring Framework’s transaction infrastructure code only marks a transaction for rollback in the case of runtime, unchecked exceptions; that is, when the thrown exception is an instance or subclass of RuntimeException.

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/data-access.html#transaction-declarative-rolling-back

So, it must stay as a type of `RuntimeException`.

Probably you have `Transactional` annotation on top of `service1.insertOne` and/or `service2.insertTwo()` methods and that's why you get `javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction marked as rollbackOnly`.

You don't need those additional annotations (if they're exist) since there is an already active transaction.

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25322944/3099704) out.

Answer (score 0):

If your `insertOne`, and `insertTwo` methods are marked as `@Transactional`, default propagation is `Required`. So you should see all that executed in one transaction. [Link to docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html)

In second case it works as it should as well. If you throw custom transaction, then Spring does not take case of it. You can update that default behavior, by providing `rollbackFor`. In that case you will expect almost the same situation as in first case.

So it is more question to you - do you want your validation to mark transaction as `rollbackOnly`, or not. I would say yes.

Perhaps question is too abstract. Let's say you are putting invoice, and positions - then I would expect this transaction to be rolled back. However, if you add group, and users... Group can go, since problem is with user.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `noRollbackFor`option of the `@Transactional` to specify for which exception should not trigger a rollback:
https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html#noRollbackFor--

```
@Transaction (noRollbackFor=YourRuntimeException.class)
void method (){
    try{
      service1.insertOne();
      service2.insertTwo();
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
    // log exception
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I am not quite quite sure if this is the right way to handle this scenario.

YES this way is fine, When you marked your method `void method ()` as Transactional , you instructed whenever there is a runtime exception, please rollback . When a code block with in the @Transactional annotated method observes a runtimeexception during execution, the Spring framework will keep it is as flag ('rollbackOnly') under ThreadLocal variable. Please note that after completion of method() , spring will commit if it finds that the flag ('rollbackOnly') is false. Otherwise spring will  instruct the transaction manager to rollback all of the inserts.

> even when the validation for service2 fails , data in service1 gets inserted, but i do see the custom exception being thrown. So i am not sure where i am going wrong

As explained above.