# Commit failure JPA transaction when invoked through JMS MessageListener

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, jms, spring-transactions, transactional

I have a code which works fine but fails when the load is high. Not able to find the route cause of it. 
Following is overview of my use case

1. I am reading message from JMS queue.
2. Calling one REST API endpoint with the message received.
3. Saving back the response received from #2 in my database.

Below is code snippet

```
 //Message Listener class which reads the messages from JMS Queue
 public class MyListener implements MessageListener {
        @Autowired
        MyDao myDao;

        @Override
        public void onMessage(Message message) {
             MyResponse resp = callRest(message);
             myDao.saveToDb(resp);
       }
    }

    //DAO class which updates my entity   
    @Component
    public class MyDao {
          @Autowired
          EntityManager entityManager;

          @Transactional
           public boolean saveToDb(MyResponse resp) {
             Query query = entityManager.createQuery("from MyTable mt where mt.id=:id");
             query.setParameter("id", myResp.getId());
             MyTable myTab = (MyTable) query.getSingleResult();
             myTab.setProcessFlag(true);
             entityManager.merge(myTab);
          }
     }
```

This works fine when I run in debug mode or when the messages are coming in queue not so frequently.

> But when messages coming in queue are very fast then I get exception
>   in `saveToDb` method as

```
org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
```

Am I doing anything wrong here or if there is some confusion between JMS and JPA transactions while multiple threads are accessing it simultaneously ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't mention your JMS provider, but several JMS implementations will call onMessage from multiple threads. So you saveToDb method could be called from multiple threads. I'm not sure where your transactions actually starts, but if you synchronize your saveToDb() method (`public boolean synchronized saveToDb(MyResponse resp)` ) does it work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This exception occurs when you invoke nested methods/services also marked as @Transactional.

[For more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42899742/5703813)