# Nested Find in JPA Insert Rethrows the Same Error

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

**User.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "User", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "emailAddress" }) )
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long userId;

    private String emailAddress;

}
```

**UserDAO.java**

```
@Repository("UserDAO")
@Transactional
public class UserDAO {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public String insert(User user) {

        try {
            entityManager.persist(user);
        } catch (PersistenceException e) {
            if (e.getCause() != null && e.getCause().getClass() == ConstraintViolationException.class) {
                try {
                    insertedUserId = getIdByEmail(user.getEmailAddress());
                } catch (Exception exception) {
                    //some error handling
                }
            }
        }

    }

    private long getIdByEmail(String emailAddress) {
        Query query = entityManager
                .createQuery(
                        "FROM User WHERE emailAddress = :emailAddress")
                .setParameter("emailAddress", emailAddress);
        User user = (User) query.getSingleResult();
        return user.getUserId();
    }

}
```

I am trying to insert a record into the user table and if the email address (which is a unique column) already exists, I want to fetch the existing record instead of inserting a new one. Now, I want to first insert and then try to catch the exception to find the record. But when I do this, I get the following the ConstraintViolationError even in the catch clause, from the find query.

> javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
>
> Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Unique index or primary key violation: "ON PUBLIC.USER(EMAILADDRESS) VALUES ('abc_fgh@aol.com', 1)"; SQL statement:
> insert into User (emailAddress, UserId) values (?, ?)

Comment: That is because the `EntityManager` still contains the offending `User` instance when the `SELECT` is attempted. Therefore, it tries to flush the context before the `SELECT` is attempted, hence the error. Call `entityManager.clear()` before the call to `getIdByEmail` to remove the offending instance from the persistence context.

Comment: @manish Thanks for the reply! I added the `entityManager.clear()` before `getByEmail()` as you had asked but now I get **org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction marked as rollbackOnly**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @manish, you first need to clear the entityManager but then you might get the following error.

> org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction marked as rollbackOnly

To solve this error just add the following line in the code. ([original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34933457/3162450))

```
TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus().setRollbackOnly();
```

So the try block in my case finally looks like -

```
try {
    entityManager.clear();
    insertedUserId = getIdByEmail(user.getEmailAddress());
    TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus().setRollbackOnly();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In real scenario i would suggest you to check if the email already exists first.If not then persist.

Edit 1: And if your intention is to save the user anyway then actually as a second option i would use `merge(user)` instead of `persist(user)`.

Comment: I realize that that would be easier but in my case, the duplicate would occur very rarely and I thought that throwing an error and dealing with the result would be faster for the majority case.