# Hibernate does not rollback in case of an exception thrown

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-jdbc, spring-orm

I have below piece of code in my project. An exception is thrown at line # 4 still my product details are saved. I am having hard time to understand why does it save product details even after throwing the exception
**I am also trying to understand if the exception thrown at line #4 is a checked or unchecked exception ? If i am throwing  "throw new Exception("Details don't match")" it is a Runtime exception I am assuming?**

```
class Product{
    @Transactional
        addDetails(){
            try{
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
               throw new Exception("Details dont match") //Line 4
            }
           productDAO.save(productDetails) 
           addAdditionalDetails(productDetails)
        }
       }

class ProductDAO {
   @Transactional
   public void save(Product productDetails){
       entitiyManager.merge(productDetails)
   }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Annotation @Transactional. How to rollback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7872773/annotation-transactional-how-to-rollback)

Answer (score 2):

> I am also trying to understand if the exception thrown at line #4 is a
>   checked or unchecked exception?

Answer: `java.lang.Exception` is a checked exception.

> If I am throwing "throw new Exception("Details don't match")" it is a
>   Runtime exception I am assuming?

Answer: No, it is not a `RuntimeException`. RuntimeException is those which extends `java.lang.RuntimeException` or its `subclass`.

In spring by Transaction is Rollback when a `Runtime` exception occurs. That means any exception thrown in a transaction which `extends RuntimeException` or its subclass will rollback it. But in your case, you are throwing `Exception` which is not a type of `RuntimeException`.

Solution:

I will suggest creating a Custom exception which extends `RuntimeExction` and throws it.

```
class UnmatchedDetailException extends RuntimeException{
    UnmatchedDetailException(String msg){
        super(msg);
    }
}
```

And then throw the `UnmatchedDetailException`

```
throw new UnmatchedDetailException("Deatils not matched");
```

Answer (score 0):

With default spring configurations, only un-checked runtime exceptions are rolled back. In order to customize this configuration, **rollbackFor** is used as a property in the **@Transactional** annotation.

For ex,

> @Transactional(rollbackFor = { MyInvalidUserException.class,
>   MyApplicationException.class }) public void method() throws
>   MyInvalidUserException,  MyApplicationException { 
>       ... 
>       ...  }