# @Transactional annotation doesn't work for method

Tags: java, database, spring-boot

I am using oracleDB and elasticsearch for persistence and if anything goes wrong in that method, it throws a custom exception. Now I need to rollback from DB if any thing fails in elastic also.

I have already added @transactional annotation on service classes. And everything I found on web.

```
@Transactional(rollbackOn = BaseException.class)
public void transaction(ab ab, a a) {
    persistenceService.save(a);
    persistenceService.updateSignalCountDb(a.abc(), a.bcd(), ab);
    elasticService.saveSignal(a);

    try {
        elasticService.updateSignalCountElastic(a);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new BaseException(ErrorCodes.FAILED_ELASTIC_SEARCH_UPDATE, e);
    }
}
```

persistenceService.save() method saves in db.
persistenceService.updateSignalCountDb() method update another table in db.
elasticService.saveSignal() method saves in elastic. throws base exception in case of failure.
elasticService.updateSignalCountElastic() method update another index in elastic. It also calls elasticService.delete() method to delete anything saved in elastic in case of failure and throws a base exception.

I expected this would work in case of any failure in the entire method. But if anything fails on elastic, i get a base exception but my data from oracle db doesn't rollback.

Comment: Check whether AUTO_COMMIT is set to false in data source configuration. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7872773/annotation-transactional-how-to-rollback

Answer (score 0):

At first glance it looks like you are doing everything right. But before you search for the reason why it doesn't work, small change in your code would prevent the problem from occurring in the first place:

```
  @Transactional(rollbackOn = BaseException.class)
  public void transaction(ab ab, a a){
    try {
      elasticService.saveSignal(a);
      elasticService.updateSignalCountElastic(a);
      persistenceService.save(a);
      persistenceService.updateSignalCountDb(a.abc(), a.bcd(), ab);
    }catch (Exception e){
      throw new BaseException(ErrorCodes.FAILED_ELASTIC_SEARCH_UPDATE, e);
    }
  }
```

In this case your exception will occur before you even save in DB and you won't have a problem

Comment: in that case if anything goes wrong with db, elastic won't be able to roll back.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you are using Spring `@Transactional`, I researched there is only
   `rollbackFor` option but not `rollbackOn`(I'm not sure this), like
   this: `@Transactional(rollbackFor = BaseException.class)`.
2. Make sure Transactional is enabled in spring configuration: `@EnableTransactionManagement`
3. In your case, only `BaseException` would trigger rollback, other `Exception` would not.

Comment: ```rollbackon``` is used in case I am using ```@Transactional``` of javax. anyways I have started using spring ```@Transactional``` with ```@EnableTransactionManagement``` in spring configuration and I am still getting same results.

Comment: Can you try `@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)` to see if rollback could be triggered?

Comment: I tried that and it doesn't work. however, I was able to recognize the issue and it resolved.

Comment: there was a silly mistake. This method was into a class that was not handled by spring. I just changed its class and get its bean into old class, it started working.