# How to rollback a transaction on any Exception

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions

```
  @Override
  @Transactional(rollbackFor=Exception.class)
  public void deletePerson(String id) throws Exception{
    PersonEntity personEntity = personrepository.findById(id);

    if(personEntity == null){
       throws new Exception("No Person found");
     }

    ElasticPersonEntity elasticPersonEntity = modelMapper.map(personEntity,ElasticPersonEntity.class);

    try{
        personrepository.delete(personEntity);
        elasticpersonrepository.delete(elasticPersonEntity); // Error Occur as Elastic search is down
     }
    catch(Exception ex){
        throws new RuntimeException();
    }
}
```

In my above code, I have to save Person data at two places Cassandra and Elastic search. Hence I need to perform delete on both as well . However if due to some reason if my elastic search is down the above code does not rollback. i.e Data is deleted from Cassandra but is still present in Elastic. Any idea of how to do so. I need to do similar modification at update, create as well.

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand why `@Transactional(rollbackFor=Exception.class)` dont do the job but as say in this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7872773/annotation-transactional-how-to-rollback) you can try to run rollback *manually*

```java
TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus().setRollbackOnly();
```