# Transactions Rollback issue in Spring

Tags: java, spring, jpa, jdbc, spring-transactions

Facing an issue while rollback saving data.

Problem:
In my java method there are three saving actions. Data save to different table. I want when a saving fails then all saved transaction will be rollback.

Example, there are three tables consist of master table and sub table. All table save in a method. APVoucherEntryDetails is the child table, when it saves fail then upper transactions should be rollback.

How can I do it ?

Thanks in advance

```
    @Override
public ApiResponse saveVoucher(APVoucherBatch batch) {
    APVoucherBatch savedBatch = voucherBatchRepo.save(batch);  //table 1
    //==========save entry=============
    List<APVoucherEntry> entryList = batch.getEntryList();
    for(APVoucherEntry info: entryList){
        info.setVoucherBatch(savedBatch);
        info.setBatchNo(savedBatch.getBatchNo());
        APVoucherEntry savedEntry = entryRepo.save(info);   //table 2

        //==========save detail=============
        List<APVoucherEntryDetails> detailsList = info.getDetailsList();
        for(APVoucherEntryDetails dtl: detailsList){
            dtl.setBatchList(savedBatch);
            dtl.setEntryInfo(savedEntry);
            detailsRepo.save(dtl);     //table 3
        }
    }
    return new ApiResponse();
}
```

Comment: Read this post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7872773/annotation-transactional-how-to-rollback. If doesn't help, please update question with specific issue you are facing

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Annotation @Transactional. How to rollback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7872773/annotation-transactional-how-to-rollback)

Comment: None of above link work for me. In a method, there are three JPARepository save statement. I want when any one throws an error each saving object will rollback.